# String format into specific pattern

Tags: java, string, format

Is there any pretty and flexible way to format String data into specific pattern, for example:

```
data input -> 0123456789
data output <- 012345/678/9
```

I did it by cutting String into multiple parts, but I'm searching for any more suitable way.

Comment: Post your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the last and 4th-2nd last in groups:

```
String formatted = str.replaceAll("(...)(.)$", "/$1/$2");
```

This captures the parts you want in groups and replaces them with intervening slashes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use replaceAll with regex to match multiple groups like so :

```
String text = "0123456789";
text = text.replaceAll("(\\d{6})(\\d{3})(.*)", "$1/$2/$3");
System.out.println(text);
```

**Output**

```
012345/678/9
```

details

- `(\d{6})` group one match 6 digits
- `(\d{3})` group two match 3 digits
- `(.*)`    group three rest of your string
- `$1/$2/$3` replace with the group 1 followed by `/` followed by group 2 followed by `/` followed by group 3

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringBuilder`'s [`insert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,char)) to insert characters at a certain index:

```
String input = "0123456789";
String output = new StringBuilder(input)
    .insert(6, "/")
    .insert(10, "/")
    .toString();
System.out.println(output); // 012345/678/9
```